# Can I add value the a cell when the date is reached?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

```
ID  first_name  last_name  age  grade       address  phone_num
1         John        Doe   12      6  444 New york    xxxxxxx
```

I want to automatically add value when the date has reached 31 May in grade column.
Let say if the date is reach 31 May then grade should be 7.

Thank you in advance

I have tried:

```
I2 = 6 
E2 = 31/05/2022
=if(TODAY() = I2,E2+1,E2)
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be (to fill in in cell "I3"):

```
I2 = 6 
E2 = 31/05/2022
=IF(TODAY() = E2,I2+1,I2)
```